# if else condition in class constructor ... is it good practice?

Tags: java, constructor, coding-style

I have written a constructor and passing one boolean flag to decide which value to set to class variable. Code is as follows

```
public PDFParagraph(PDFPhrase phrase,boolean isRtl) {
            super(phrase);
            if(isRtl)
                    this.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_RIGHT);
            else
                    this.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_LEFT);
    }
```

Now I am confused and not sure if I shall add if...else conditions in constructor. Is it good style to set the class varible value?

Thanks,
Hanumant.

Comment: There's no need to put 'this' in front of method invocations.

Comment: Agreed with Steve. AFAIK, there are only 2 instances where `this` is needed: (1) When there is ambiguity between a local and member var, e.g. `this.myInt = myInt;`, or (2) if you're passing the member as a parameter, e.g. `new BinaryFormatter().Serialize(fileStream, this);` This goes for variables, properties, functions, etc...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Conditionals in constructors aren't problematic per se. However, in this instance, I'd be inclined to write your constructor like this:

```
public PDFParagraph(PDFPhrase phrase, boolean isRtl) {
    super(phrase);
    setAlignment(isRtl ? Element.ALIGN_RIGHT : Element.ALIGN_LEFT);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no style issue with using an `if` / `else` to do that.  However:

- You could write it more simply:

  ```
  setAlignment(isRtl ? Element.ALIGN_RIGHT : Element.ALIGN_LEFT);
  ```
- A lot of people (myself included) think that you should always put curly braces around the "then" and "else" statements.

---

On a related point: if you find yourself writing a constructor that looks like this:

```
public Thing(boolean cond, ...) {
    super(...);
    if (cond) {
        // Lots of statements
    } else {
        // Lots of different statements
    }
    ...
}
```

it is possibly an indication that you need to refactor your constructors.  (Or possibly not ... it depends on the details.)

Comment: or perhaps that you should have two classes related by inheritance.

Comment: Yea ... that's another possible refactoring.  It all depends on the details.

Answer (score 1):

It might be more clear to users of your constructor if you just pass the initial alignment to set, especially if it's an `Enum` and those are the only possibilities. If however you're trying to restrict the initial alignment and it's something like a `String`, what you're doing seems fine. You still might want to consider an `Enum` for clarity though. It's easier to read than `true` or `false` being passed into a constructor.

Comment: This becomes an bigger issue once you have more than one such boolean argument ("what did `true, false` mean? Or did I want to write `false, true` here?")

Comment: @Joachim: agree, definitely gets increasingly confusing with more booleans.

Comment: @Joachim Sauer, @WhiteFang34, thanks for your input, I have used enum instead of boolean.

Answer (score 1):

Of course you can add if/else statements to the constructor.

It's usually best practice to keep methods as atomic (short and to-the-point) and clearly-defined as possible. This goes for the constructor also. You want the constructor to set up your object given the parameters you pass.

If you need an if/else, then you can put one in.
You can even go crazy and put a for loop in if you need to! ;)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you use an enum and a switch statement instead of a boolean.  What happens when you add another alignment?